# Show that $\widehat{f*g}(n) = \hat{f}(n)\hat{g}(n)$.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

> (Tao Analysis 2, P.125, Q.5.5.3) If $f \in C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{C})$ and $P$ is a trigonometric polynomial, show that
> $$\widehat{f*P}(n) = \hat{f}(n)c_n = \hat{f}(n)\hat{P}(n)$$
> for all integers $n$. More generally, if $f, g \in C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{C})$, show that
> $$\widehat{f*g}(n) = \hat{f}(n)\hat{g}(n)$$
> for all integers $n$.

$\hat{f}: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ defined by $\hat{f}(n) : = \langle f, e_n \rangle$, where $e_n(x) : = e^{2\pi i n x}$. I denote the convolution operation by $*$.

Let $P(x) = \sum_{m= -M}^M c_m e_m(x)$ for some $c_m \in \mathbb{C}$.Then,
$$\widehat{f*P}(n) =\langle f*P, e_n \rangle = \sum_{m= -M}^M c_m \langle f * e_m, e_n \rangle = \sum_{m= -M}^M c_m \hat{f}(m) \langle  e_m, e_n \rangle = c_n \hat{f}(n).$$

Similarly, I can show that $c_n = \hat{P} (n)$. I am unsure about the second part. I know that by Weierstrass approximation theorem, for any $g \in C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{C})$, there exists a trigonometric polynomial $P$ such that for every $\epsilon$, $||g - P||_{\infty} \le \epsilon$. Therefore, intuitively, by the first part of the exercise, the second part also holds. But, I don't know how to prove it rigorously. I would appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: $|\widehat {f*g_1-f*g_2}| \leq \|f*{g_1-g_2}\|_1 \leq \|f\|_1 \|g_1-g_2\|_1\leq \|f\|_1 \|g_1-g_2\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: Still can't figure it out.
Can you provide some details about the proof?